Product of 2 normal variables with positive means
Suppose $X \sim N(1,1)$, $Y \sim N(1,1)$ are iid normal random variables. My research problem is finding out the asymptotics of the tail function of XY (since the explicit formula is too complicated).
If I'm not mistaken, the expression should look like:
$$\begin{align}&\mathbb{P}(XY > z) = \mathbb{P}(XY > z, X > 0) + \mathbb{P}(XY > z, X < 0)
 \\&= \mathbb{P}\left(Y > \frac{z}{X}, X > 0\right) + \mathbb{P}\left(Y < \frac{z}{X}, X < 0\right)
 \\&= \int_0^\infty f_X(x) \left( \int_{\frac{z}{x}}^\infty f_Y(y) \, dy \right) dx + \int_{-\infty}^0 f_X(x) \left( \int_{-\infty}^{\frac{z}{x}} f_Y(y) \, dy \right) dx
\\&=\int_0^\infty f(x) \overline{F}\left(\frac{z}{x}\right) dx + \int_{-\infty}^0 f(x) {F}\left(\dfrac{z}{x}\right) dx
:=I_1+I_2.
\end{align}$$
Using the well-known asymptotics of $\overline{F}$ for integral $I_1$ we get
$$ I_1=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^\infty \left(\frac{z}{x}-1\right)^{-1} e^{-\frac{1}{2}((x-1)^2+(\frac{z}{x}-1)^2)}  dx. $$
Basically, I want to analyze this integral. The main issue is that I'm unsure which method I should use. The saddle point method this time doesn't work to my concern. Maybe someone has some ideas?

As a side note, the PDF of $Z = XY$ is basically a modified Bessel function (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_of_the_product_of_two_random_variables#Independent_central-normal_distributions).

From
$$\Pr (X Y<z)=\Pr \left(X<\frac{z}{Y}\right)=\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \text{dPr}(Y<y) \Pr \left(X<\frac{z}{y}\right) $$
and
$$\text{dPr}(X Y<z)=\text{dPr}\left(X<\frac{z}{Y}\right)=\int_{-\infty \
}^{\infty } \text{dPr}(Y<y) \quad  \text{dPr}\left(X<\frac{z}{y}\right) \, \
=\frac{\text{dz}}{2 \pi  \sigma  \tau } \ \left(\int_0^{\infty } \
\frac{e^{-\frac{y^2}{2 \sigma ^2}} e^{-\frac{\left(\frac{z}{y}\right)^2}{2 \tau ^2}}}{y^2} \, dy+\ldots \right) $$
$$\left( \int_0^{\infty } e^{-\frac{y^2}{2 \sigma ^2}} \ e^{-\frac{\left(\frac{z}{y}\right)^2} {2 \tau ^2}} \frac{1}{y^2} \, dy\right)^2 \ = \ \frac{\pi  \tau ^2 e^{-\frac{2 z}{\sigma  \tau }}}{2 z^2} $$
and similar with inverted signs for the negative axis.

Sorry, I'm not quite sure whether this is right and how you got the result, can you please enhance the proof? Thanks!
